# Average engagement time per screen different on firebase vs bigquery

Tags: google-bigquery

Here is my code to calculate average engagement time per screen in bigquery:

```
select 

event_date,

params1.value.string_value as screen_name,

avg(params2.value.int_value/60000) as avg_engagement_time_min,

FROM
      `table_name` as base, unnest(event_params) as params1 , unnest(event_params) as params2 
      where event_name = 'user_engagement'
      and params1.key='firebase_screen'
      and params2.key='engagement_time_msec'


AND event_date BETWEEN @DS_START_DATE AND @DS_END_DATE


group by 1,2
order by 1,avg_engagement_time_min desc
```

The results are quite different from the Firebase dashboard, and I have trouble understanding why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the difference of results between the two because GA uses [HLL++](https://developers.google.com/analytics/blog/2022/hll) Algorithm.

> Google Analytics uses HyperLogLog++ (HLL++) algorithm to estimate cardinality for common metrics including Active Users and Sessions. That means when you view the unique count of these metrics in the UI or via the API, they are an approximation with a certain precision. In BigQuery, since you have access to the granular data, you can calculate the exact cardinality for these metrics. So metrics can vary by a small percentage.

A good reference for this difference is further explained here:

https://developers.google.com/analytics/blog/2023/bigquery-vs-ui